# Import a Unity Asset Package from https://www.heroforge.com

Tags: unity

I want to import my character created in heroforge into blender to do some custom rendering.

I bought the Character as a Unity-Asset for 3D Tabletop Programs. As i a fairly noob in 3D modeling i followed the blender parts of this Guide https://www.reddit.com/r/talespire/comments/obx9tm/a_stepbystep_tutorial_to_get_your_hero_forge/ .

Textures extraced from the UnityPackage are:(texture_diffuse.png, texture_emissive.png, texture_metal.png, texture_normal.png, texture_occlusion.png)

The Diffuse Texture is mentioned in the guide and is reponsible for basic coloring, the others are not mentioned but should be relevant for light-reflection and surface details right?

This worked partly, what seems missing are some 'effects':
What works: Mesh itself, basic coloring
After experimenting and following some tutorials it seems that i got the normal map working.
Rendering in Blender
[image]
Rendering from Heroforge
[image]

So how do apply the other render effects and other things described in the Unity Package (it contains some kind of Material properties and some kind of armature i think) to recreate the rendering from heroforge?

Comment: Depending on the complexity it may not be possible to do it, Unity's shaders and Blender's shaders are not compatible. (unless written in OSL which I don't think it's going to be). It looks from the pictures that you're missing a metallic or specular or roughness map since it's mainly the reflections that differ

Answer (score 2):

After following some tutorials and doing research, i got a nearly identical render setup in blender.

- texture_emissive.png:
  should obviously put into the Emission Input
- texture_metal.png:
  Unity saves the the Metalness as greyscale in one Channel and Glossiness in the Alphachannel into one map, Glossiness should put [inverted](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRi1FmfrGjg) into the Roughness input
- texture_normal.png:
  [some Sources](https://bgolus.medium.com/generating-perfect-normal-maps-for-unity-f929e673fc57#5410) say Unity uses the same Format as Blender, [other](https://answers.unity.com/questions/28850/tangent-normal-map-produces-reversed-effects.html)(older) sources say, the Red and Green Channel are inverted.
  i'm still not sure which one is correct
- texture_occlusion.png: seems not used with realistic calculated lights

My node setup
[image]

I may add some subsurface scattering to the skin which seems not present in the orignial model. (thanks to the Donut tutorial for this info)